# How to run a piece of code in a batch file for fixed interval of time say 2hrs and then continue to the remaining code?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have a batch file that contains :

```
:GO
    FOR %%G IN (1,2) DO (copy path1\Image_%%G.jpg "path2")
    TIMEOUT 300
    FOR %%G IN (1,2) DO ren "path2\Image_%%G.jpg" Modified_%%G.jpg
    TIMEOUT 300
    FOR %%G IN (1,2) DO del "path2\Modified_%%G.jpg"
    TIMEOUT 300
goto GO
```

I want this code to execute for 5 hrs and after that the remaining lines of the batch script should be executed. Can someone please help me with this if it is possible??

Comment: So this must run continuously for 5 hours, then only execute the next line?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that uses your time variable:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=," %%i in ("%time::=%") do set /a future=%%i+3600

:rerun
timeout /t 2 >nul 2>&1

echo run the code you want to run for 5 hours here...

for /f "delims=," %%i in ("%time::=%") do if "%%i" geq "%future%" (
      echo run the code here when 3600 seconds have passed
      goto :eof
    ) else (
      echo %%i less than %future%
      goto rerun
    )
)
```

I have not included your code as it is a bit of a mess, but you'll get the idea `:)`